# Это предложение грамматически верно написано?

Tags: грамматика

*Гражданам, которые в будущем выйдут на пенсию, обещают ежегодную надбавку в размере 1 тыс рублей, хотя это несравнимо с тем, сколько они потеряют за те годы, в которые они получали бы пенсию в случае неизменности пенсионного возраст.*

Это предложение грамматически верно написано? Если нет, как лучше исправить? Но важно оставить одним предложением, не дробить.

Comment: Или лучше так? «Гражданам, которые в будущем выйдут на пенсию, обещают ежегодную надбавку в размере 1 тыс рублей, хотя это несравнимо с тем, сколько они потеряют за те годы, в которые они МОГЛИ БЫ получать пенсию в случае неизменности пенсионного возраста.

Answer (score 1):

Гражданам, которые в будущем выйдут на пенсию, обещают ежегодную надбавку в размере 1 тыс рублей, хотя это несравнимо с тем, что они могли бы получить в виде пенсии за годы, на которые увеличен пенсионный возраст.

Примечания

- Не совсем корректно говорить, что они будут что-то **терять** за определенные годы (в том смысле, что на протяжении определенного количества лет), скорее они просто что-то **не получат**.
- Корректно: "несравнимо с тем, что" или "несравнимо с теми деньгами, которые".
- Неудачно и требует исправления: "за те годы, в которые".

Answer (score 0):

Сама формулировка предложения не совсем корректна.

*По словам вице-премьера [**Татьяны Голиковой**](https://ria.ru/society/20180616/1522855891.html), годовой доход пенсионеров в следующем году увеличится приблизительно на 12 тысяч рублей, то есть в среднем **на тысячу рублей в месяц.** Это произойдет благодаря повышению пенсионного возраста. По словам Голиковой, в дальнейшем эту сумму будут индексировать в установленном порядке.*

Я бы написала так:
Гражданам, которые в будущем выйдут на пенсию, обещана ежемесячная надбавка в размере одной тысячи рублей — это несравнимо меньше того, что они недополучат за время, на которое будет увеличен пенсионный возраст.

Или так:
Гражданам, которые в будущем выйдут на пенсию, обещана ежемесячная надбавка в размере одной тысячи рублей — эта сумма не сравнима с той, которую они недополучат за те годы, на которые будет увеличен возраст выхода на пенсию.

Comment: (1) В месяц или в год — разница невелика, главное "глаголом жечь сердца людей". (2) По словам вице-премьера, это произойдет "благодаря", то есть явление положительное, деньги приносит, а Вы — недополучат!   (3)  Ставить тире или слово *хотя* — это зависит от контекста. (4) На мой взглад, мой вариант "могли бы получить в виде пенсии" яснее для непонятливых , чем просто "недополучат".

Comment: Да, согласна - хрен редьки не слаще (да и жжёным глаголом сыт не будешь). _...благодаря повышению пенсионного возраста._ (Был у меня недавно такой вопрос: благодаря в отрицательном контексте.) Это с какой стороны посмотреть! Так вот, для людей предпенсионного возраста нововведение - как обухом по голове, а для экономящего государства - плюсик (меньше пенсионный контингент - меньше на него расходов). Так что недополучат люди, недополучат!